# Are there any free online questionnaire/survey sites that also measure the time it takes for participants to answer each question?

Tags: reaction-time, survey

I'm doing a research experiment where I'm trying to measure the time it takes for participants to answer certain questions in an online questionnaire/survey. More specifically, I will be asking participants to examine a graphic image and answer a question about it. An important part of this research is recording how long it takes participants to respond. Any suggestions are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here are a couple of suggestions:

- [Inquisit](http://www.millisecond.com/) records the timing of each response and can be run online.
  If you care about timing a lot and you need to run the study online, then this is quite a good option.
- [Qualtrics](http://www.qualtrics.com/) can record various features of survey delivery time. In particular, you can record time spent on each survey page. If you have one question per page, this can approximate time to respond to the item. This can be useful if you want to identify participants who are not reading items. However, I wouldn't use Qualtrics for cognitive reaction time based experiments. Note also that in order to record item response times you need to manually set this for each survey page.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Qualtrics for reaction time based experiments?

Comment: @AlexL I don't think qualtrics supports that kind of experiment by default. That said, it does allow java script so perhaps there's something you can do with that. And maybe you can embed html in some kind of way.